# jQuery - Total and extra divs not showing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to show the total amount of selected persons, and also add that number of extra divs in the form

This is me code: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9rspxhjy/1/) , but the total amount of persons is not showing also the extra divs are not working.

This is an example how it should be like : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5tj1sec6/15/)

What is wrong? And how can i make this work? Thanks!

This is my JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sum = 0;
    $(document).on('change', 'div select',function(){
        sum = 0;
       $('div select').each(function(){
           var thisVal = parseInt($(this).val());
           sum += thisVal;
       });
        $('#person-total').text(sum);
        // you can use here 

        // remove all divs
        $('div[class^="passenger"]').remove();
        // to show divs depending on number of persons
        for(var i = 1 ; i <= sum ; i++){
            $('body').append('<div class="passenger'+i+'"><label for="passenger_name">Passenger '+i+'</label><input name="passenger_name_'+i+'" type="text" id="passenger_name" placeholder="FIRSTNAME"><input name="passenger_lname_'+i+'" type="text" id="passenger_lname" placeholder="LASTNAME"><input name="passenger_age_'+i+'" type="text" id="passenger_age" placeholder="AGE"></div>');
        }
    });
});
```

I found the problem i tink, its calculating al selected options., but how can i change this :

```
$(document).on('change', 'div select',function(){
        sum = 0;
       $('div select').each(function(){
           var thisVal = parseInt($(this).val());
           sum += thisVal;
       });
```

Special for working for 1 div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your "choose a trip" drop down matches the selector `'div select'`, so it is included in the `.each()` loop.  So when you call

```
parseInt($(this).val());
```

You end up with `NaN` which stands for "Not a Number".

I added a class of `"count-select"` to each of the select elements that should be included in this function, and modified the JavaScript as follows:

#### JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $(document).on('change', '.count-select', function () {
        sum = 0;
        $('.count-select').each(function () {
            var thisVal = parseInt($(this).val());
            sum += thisVal;
        });
        $('#person-total').text(sum);
        // you can use here 

        // remove all divs
        $('div[class^="passenger"]').remove();
        // to show divs depending on number of persons
        for (var i = 1; i <= sum; i++) {
            $('body').append('<div class="passenger' + i + '"><label for="passenger_name">Passenger ' + i + '</label><input name="passenger_name_' + i + '" type="text" id="passenger_name" placeholder="FIRSTNAME"><input name="passenger_lname_' + i + '" type="text" id="passenger_lname" placeholder="LASTNAME"><input name="passenger_age_' + i + '" type="text" id="passenger_age" placeholder="AGE"></div>');
        }
    });
});
```

Here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/voveson/9rspxhjy/2/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thans Sir, that was the problem! Thankls